# How to display the amount of negative numbers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, negative-number

How to display the amount of negative numbers in an array?

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int arrayNumbers[] = { 3, 4, 7, -3, -2};
    for (int i = 0; i <= arrayNumbers.length; i++){
        int negativeCount = 0;
        if (arrayNumbers[i] >= 0){
                negativeCount++;
    }
    System.out.println(negativeCount);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it, but you keep reinitializing the counter.  Take `int negativeCount = 0;` out and put it before the loop.

EDIT
As another user has mentioned in the comment, you are counting positive numbers instead of negative ones.  So, fix the `if (arrayNumbers[i] >= 0)` also.

Comment: I think he is checking for positive numbers.

Comment: @freebird I didn't notice that.  Thanks for pointing that out.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You were making `negativeCount` variable back to 0 everytime you found a negative number and also you need to check if `arrayNumbers[i]<0`

```
    public static void main(String args[])
     {
            int arrayNumbers[] = { 3, 4, 7, -3, -2};
            int negativeCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= arrayNumbers.length; i++)
            {

              if (arrayNumbers[i] < 0)
               {
                 negativeCount++;
               }

            }

             System.out.println(negativeCount);
      }

        }
```

Comment: System.out.println(negativeCount);
Should be out of for loop too. If you want to display the total number! Not to display every time! Also there is one } extra here!

Answer (score 0):

you need to do the following;

1) declare the variable negativeCount outside the loop.

2) change the of statememt's condition to less than 0 and not greater or equal. (or u can just add a not operator infront of the current condition.

Comment: I only want to print the number "2." Thank you regardless!

Comment: place the print statement out of the loop

Comment: Change the for loop condition to arrayNumbers[i]<0 , and not to arrayNumbers[i]<=0